# WebGL shader flickering

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, shader

I'm a beginner on WebGL and shaders, so if you find upgrades/optimizations for my code, I would love to see them.

**My problem:**

I have two WebGL instances (with curtainsjs) on two separate pages, one is working but not the other. They basically have the same code. The only thing that is different is the size of the output canvas. For the bugged one, it's the size of an image (not full page width and height), and for the working one it take the whole viewport.

The bugged one is flickery, like a stroboscopic white effect (see here: https://youtu.be/Yxkmm0HgNlE) but only on iOS devices (working fine on windows, macos, android, but not on ipad and iphone).

**Things I already tried:**

- lowp, mediump, highp
- gl.flutch()
- change "translate" value of vectors positions

Nothing worked.

Here is the shaders :

**Vertex**

```
    #ifdef GL_ES
    precision highp float;
    #endif

    attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
    uniform float uTime;
    uniform float uMouseMoveStrength;
    uniform vec2 uMousePosition;

    uniform mat4 uTextureMatrix0;

    varying vec3 vVertexPosition;
    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

    void main() {

      vec3 vertexPosition = aVertexPosition;

              float distanceFromMouse = distance(uMousePosition, vec2(vertexPosition.x, vertexPosition.y));

              float waveSinusoid = cos(5.0 * (distanceFromMouse - (uTime / 75.0)));

              float distanceStrength = (0.4 / (distanceFromMouse + 0.4));

              float distortionEffect = distanceStrength * waveSinusoid * uMouseMoveStrength;

              vertexPosition.z +=  distortionEffect / 30.0;
              vertexPosition.x +=  (distortionEffect / 10.0 * (uMousePosition.x - vertexPosition.x));
              vertexPosition.y +=  distortionEffect / 30.0 * (uMousePosition.y - vertexPosition.y);
            gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.05);

            vTextureCoord = (uTextureMatrix0 * vec4(aTextureCoord, 0.0, 1.0)).xy;
            vVertexPosition = vertexPosition;
    }
```

**Fragment:**

```
      #ifdef GL_ES
      precision highp float;
      #endif

      varying vec3 vVertexPosition;
      varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

      uniform sampler2D uSampler0;
      void main() {

        vec2 textureCoord = vTextureCoord;

        gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler0, textureCoord);
      }
```

Comment: It's got nothing to do with your shaders. It's most likely [a known bug in Safari on iOS](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=159608)

Comment: Oh ok I see. But isn't that weird that it's working fine on the other page ?
I'll just delete the webgl effect on iOS then!

Comment: The bug linked as nothing to do with your shader or your effect. Rather it has to do with whether or not you created your webgl context with `preserveDrawingBuffer: true`. So check that and remove `preserveDrawingBuffer: true` when creating the WebGL context. If that is not your issue then you'll need to post a [miminal reproducable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349790/128511) ideally in a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)